# What hardware/platform difference could cause an XAML-WPF multibinding to CheckBox to fail?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox, multibinding

This is a follow up to [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22355609/how-can-i-dynamically-change-the-converter-on-datagridtextcolumn-binding-in-wpf) (see code example there and my last comment on the accepted answer). In short, I've got a `Multibinding` on a WPF `DataGridTextColumn` to a (home-grown) `Person` object and a `CheckBox`. On several computers that I have in the office, it works as expected - the content is altered based on the state of the `CheckBox` according to my object that implements the `IMultiValueConverter` interface - but on all four computers tested (so far) in the field, it fails.

The failure appears to be due to a faulty binding, as the object that is passed to the `IMultiValueConverter` value array has type `MS.Internal.NamedObject`, which I suspect is the null data binding object, `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` (but `ToString()` didn't give a clearer indication).

Ostensibly, these computers are identically provisioned, though they're not literally from a cloned image. The question I have is what aspect(s) of the hardware and/or platform might possibly lead to a different behavior of the `Multibinding`? Or what can I try to further investigate the source of the problem? (Disclaimer: I'm pretty much a newbie to WPF and XAML.)

Comment: Perhaps [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227083/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-ms-internal-namedobject-to-custom-type) is related? The ultimate cause is a bug in the WPF 4 framework, and there is some workarounds posted on the [official bug report page](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/619658/wpf-virtualized-control-disconnecteditem-reference-when-datacontext-switch)

Comment: Holy @#$^$!! Thank you! I'd seen that post, but since I had a hard time telling if it was or was not the same issue, I didn't read the bug report. Turns out that installing .NET 4.5.1 fixes the issue. Post a response, and I'll accept it as answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a search for `MS.Internal.NamedObject` and came to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8227083/302677) which sounds like it could be related.

The ultimate cause is a bug in the WPF 4 framework related to a virtualized control binding to an ObservableCollection, and changing the DataContext. There is some workarounds posted on the [official bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/619658/wpf-virtualized-control-disconnecteditem-reference-when-datacontext-switch) page, and the easiest solution appears to be to upgrade your version of the framework if you can.